# how can i prevent access to routes in react js

Tags: react-redux

I am using react-redux for changing the state in my app.In my router page how can I route based on conditions.ie,If the user logged status is true then if i go to the login component it must redirect to the home component and the user logged status is false,if i go to the home component it must redirect to the login component.

**routes.js**

```
const routes=() => (
    <Router>
        <div>
            <Header />
                <Route exact path="/" render={ props =>  <div><FirstConnectedComponent /><SecondConnectedComponent /></div>} />
                <Route path="/login" component={ requireAuth(Login) } />
                <Route path="/register" component={ UserReg } />
                <Route path="/home" component={ Home } />
            <Footer />
        </div>
    </Router>

)
export default routes;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a new route component called `PrivateRoute`

**PrivateRoute.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
        localStorage.getItem('authenticated')
            ? <Component {...props} />
            : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
    )} />
)
```

**index.js**

First import it then use -

```
<PrivateRoute path="/" component={MyComponent} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a function call :
`onEnter={this.requireAuth.bind(this)}`

And the function could be something like this :

```
requireAuth(nextState, replace) {
    if (this.user === undefined || this.user === null) {
        replace('/login');
    }
}
```